# Xamarin Forms Picker ItemSource values localize from XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code -

```
<Picker
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   SelectedIndex="{Binding GenderIndex}"
   VerticalOptions="Center">
   <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>Man</x:String>
        <x:String>Woman</x:String>
   </Picker.Items>
```

I want localize values "Man" and "Woman"

I Have `TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension` and use this in XAML

`Text="{extensions:Translate LastName}"` and it work good

But when i try use

```
<Picker
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   SelectedIndex="{Binding GenderIndex}"
   VerticalOptions="Center">
   <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>{extensions:Translate Man}</x:String>
        <x:String>{extensions:Translate Woman}</x:String>
   </Picker.Items>
```

Device display not values, but `{extensions:Translate Man}`.

Also I can't use Binding for ItemsSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you embed into `<x:String>` like that - it will be treated like string. Try using element syntax:

```
<Picker.Items>
    <extensions:Translate PropertyName="Man" />
</Picker.Items>
```

`PropertyName` corresponds to the default property on your markup extension.